# How to move a plotted line on the timeline X axis?

Tags: python, ggplot2, plot, line

I have this graph

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfIRQ.png)

and this code:

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')

plt.plot(df1['Close'], color='b', label='Historical closing price')
plt.plot(df1_30_pred, color='r', label='30 days prediction')
plt.plot(dftoday['Close'],color='g', label='Real closing price for 30 days')
plt.plot([coefficients[0]*x + coefficients[1] for x in range(len(df1_30_pred))],color='orange', label='30 days prediction trend')

# Adding legend, which helps recognizing the curves according to color
plt.legend(loc='upper left')

plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 300, 10),rotation=45)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 200, 10))

plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.title('AAPL 30 day prediction', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel("Date", fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel("Closing price $", fontsize=18)
plt.show()
```

I want to move the orange trend line to place it on top of the red graph, so it will be between the dates is calculated for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, specify the indexes 'df1_30_pred'.
If, as I indicated, it does not work, then give all the data(dataframe). I'll try to solve the problem.

```
 plt.plot(df1_30_pred.index, [coefficients[0]*x + coefficients[1] for x in range(len(df1_30_pred))],color='orange', label='30 days prediction trend')
```